# how to receive string from COM port displayed on 2 textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have 2 data strings (eg: string "1data2DATA") from a COM port. I want string "1data" to show up in textbox_1 and string "2DATA" to show up in textextbox_2. How should I do?

image:
[image]

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) // nhan dulieu tu cong COM
{
    string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    SetText(data);
}

private void SetText(string text)
{
    //if (text[0] == 'A')        // test thử 
   // {
        if (this.tBoxCV1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText); // khởi tạo 1 delegate mới gọi đến SetText
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.tBoxCV1.Text += text;
            if (text == "1")
            {
                this.tBoxCV1.Clear();
            }
        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: The question is a little unclear. Is the text data always going to be "1data2DATA" or will the contents vary?

Comment: contents "data or DATA"will vary. '1' represents textbox_1, "2" represents textbox_2.

Comment: Using `string.Split()` as djv said is the best approach if 1 and 2 are consistent data boundary delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the format will always be

> "**1**somecharacterswithnonumbers**2**othercharacterswithoutnumbers"

then you can split on the character `2`

```cs
private void SetText(string text)
{
    if (this.tBoxCV1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(SetText), new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        var results = text.Split('2');
        results[1] = '2' + results[1];

        this.tBoxCV1.Text += results[0];
        if (results[0] == "1")
            this.tBoxCV1.Clear();
        this.tBoxCV2.Text += results[1];
        if (results[1] == "2")
            this.tBoxCV2.Clear();
    }
}
```

But if you may receive a `2` in either data, then I don't see how this is possible, and `1` and `2` would make terrible delimiters.

Comment: Thank you very much! But if data is uploaded to the COM port character by character, and it is transferred to the COM port continuously. How should I handle it? 
I used this command ( data += serialPort1.ReadExisting(); )to match your code but it didn't work.
Sorry my english is pretty bad.

Comment: If it is transferred by character individually, you will need a mechanism for the serial port to instruct your application it has finished sending data. An array of `chars` can be converted to a string and manipulated as djv explained.

Comment: @Linux the data being transferred character by character is a critical point which should have been in your question. Also how long does it take for all the data to be transferred? Do you need to update the TextBoxes as you receive characters or can you update once you have received it all? Is there a EOF character to look for to signal it is complete?